# Stuck with undefined function

Tags: javascript

I am new to the javascript and I stuck right here:
There is a smaller image which represents the normal-sized img and when its clicked I want to open the bigger image which is in the other div and I have other images too

```html
<li>
  <div>
    <span>
          <img onclick="cimgOpenning('ci-1')" src="resim/live-30.jpg" alt="asd" />
        </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="ci-1" class="cimg">
      <img src="resim/live-30.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div>
    <span>
          <img onclick="cimgOpenning('ci-2')" src="resim/live-31.jpg" alt="asd" />
        </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="ci-2" class="cimg">
      <img src="resim/live-31.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
<script>
  function cimgOpenning(e) {
    if (document.getElementById(e).style.maxWidth == "0") {
      document.getElementById(e).style.maxWidth = "100px";
    } else {
      document.getElementById(e).style.maxWidth = "0";
    }
  }
</script>
```

What I want is when the user clicked any of the smaller images opens the bigger image of itself, but I am getting continuously undefined error.

***EDİT:***
Its seems i maked a ruckus right below, sorry about that. I tried my best to gather the this section's code but best i could is this one: [FIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/elleston/1n9ups82/18/)

Its a little bit confusing code but bear with me please

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: What is undefined?

Comment: cimgOpenning is not defined, its says @evolutionxbox

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I don't think the stacksnippet helps here. The source code order may be a factor.

Comment: Please may you update the question to include a [mcve] of the issue? The current stacksnippet is too unclear.

Comment: @evolutionxbox i will update the code in 10 min, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to do that you could try this:
small image

```
      <span>
      <img onclick="cimgOpenning(this)" src="resim/live-30.jpg" alt="asd" />
      </span>
```

other div to display bigger image

```
      <div id="ci-2" style="display:none; width:100%" class="cimg">
      <img src="empty" alt="" />
      </div>
```

the javascript

```
function cimgOpenning(e) {
var smallImageSrc = e.getAttribute("src");
var bigImageContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("cimg")[0];
var bigImage = bigImageContainer.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
bigImage.src = smallImageSrc;
bigImageContainer.style.display = "block"
}
```

the function will get the src attribute of any small image that call the function then set the src to the src of the bigger image and replace the "display none" of the bigger image container with "display block" style i.e it will show it, that's it hope this helped you?

Comment: This seems better way to do it, so i will take this one. thank you so much, good sir. It will be helpful with page load speed.

Comment: have you tried it?, if there is any bug in it tell me.

Comment: i just changed some lines and its all good, thank you again ((:

Answer (score 0):

I just added a background, height, and a default max-width to see the changes.

I also inverted the condition since `document.getElementById(e).style.maxWidth` starts with a blank string. So if it's blank or 0, I make the width 100px.

```css
.cimg {
  max-width: 0px;
  background: black;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <div>
    <span>
      <img onclick="cimgOpenning('ci-1')" src="resim/live-30.jpg" alt="asd" />
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="ci-1" class="cimg">
      <img src="resim/live-30.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div>
    <span>
      <img onclick="cimgOpenning('ci-2')" src="resim/live-31.jpg" alt="asd" />
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="ci-2" class="cimg">
      <img src="resim/live-31.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

<script>
  function cimgOpenning(e) {
    if (document.getElementById(e).style.maxWidth == "100px") {
      document.getElementById(e).style.maxWidth = "0px";
    } else {
      document.getElementById(e).style.maxWidth = "100px";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please may you clarify what you have changed/why your answer works?

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged, please provide explanation

Comment: Sorry, I just posted the answer (1 min ago), I usually post the code first then edit the post to follow-up explanation. It is now updated.

Comment: May you also explain what you did to resolve the OP's issue of seeing the error "cimgOpenning is not defined"?